# Usng PHP to connect to a mySQL, connection worked yesterday but not today

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple HTML form that will add data to a remotely hosted My SQL database. I'm pulling my hair out because the connection code that I made yesterday stopped working today for no apparent reason.

Here's the code I had:

```
<?php
$servername = "sql309.myservername.com";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The error message that I get is: 
"Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusername'@'an.ip.address' (using password: YES)"

I noticed that phpmyadmin has my username listed as 'myusername@a.different.ip.address', and when I replaces the username string with 'myusername@a.different.ip.address', the error message becomes:

"Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusername@a.different.ip.address'@'an.ip.address' (using password: YES)"

How do I tell the code to use 'myusername'@'a.different.ip.address' ? Or is there a different problem?

Comment: you have dbname in your $conn variable as `dbname=mydbname`.  Shouldn't that be your variable `dbname=$dbname`?

Comment: Thanks Robert, but that wasn't causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Turns out the password had reverted to the default, rather than new password that I set and had working yesterday.